# Using Medley.core lib in clojure repl

Tags: clojure, libraries, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to use the medley library directly in clojure's repl without adding it to the `:dependencies` in the `project.clj` file? Something like `(use 'medley.core)`?

Comment: Not if it's not in your classpath. Which is what the `:dependencies` section of the `project.clj` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) to your *$HOME/.lein/profiles.clj* file

```
{:user {
    :dependencies [[com.cemerick/pomegranate "0.3.0"]]
 }}
```

Then, from the repl, you can require pomegranate functions with:

```
 (use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies)])
```

Then add your dependency like this:

```
  (add-dependencies
     :coordinates '[[incanter "1.2.3"]]
     :repositories {"clojars" "http://clojars.org/repo"}))
```

Most of the time, Clojure libraries do use a maven compatible repository named [clojars](https://clojars.org/), hence the extra repository, but if the library is on the [maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/), no need for the extra repository definition.

For example, bootstrap-clj is on [central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.sebhoss/bootstrap-clj), so in that case, the below is enough:

```
  (add-dependencies 
   :coordinates '[[com.github.sebhoss/bootstrap-clj "2.0.0"]])
```

Voila.

Comment: What does it mean: If the library is on central? I just tried it but in repl i get the error: `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: cemerick.pomegranate.aether/mavan-central, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:65)`